# django formsets can_delete header

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am new to django , please bear with me ..

created a template using django formsets and it works all good except i am not able to give header to the can_delete column .

My Django `views.py` looks like :

```
def add_expenditure(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    ExpFormSet = modelformset_factory(Expenditure,extra=1,max_num=10,fields=('exp_date', 'description','amount'),can_delete=True)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = ExpFormSet(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save(commit=True)
            formset = ExpFormSet()
        else:
            print "errors in formset are ",formset.errors
    else:
        formset = ExpFormSet(queryset=Expenditure.objects.none())
    return render_to_response('moni/add_expenditure.html', {'formset':formset}, context)
```

templete form code is as below :

```
<form id="expenditure_form" method="post"  action="/moni/add_expenditure/">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table border=10>
            <tr>
                <th>Serial No.</th>
                <th><label >Date:</label></th>
                <th><label for="id_description">Description:</label></th>
                <th><label for="id_amount">Amount</label></th>
            </tr>

            {{ formset.management_form }}
            {% for form in formset %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
                    {% for field in form %}
                        <td>  {{ field.class }} {{ field }}
                            {% if field.name == "exp_date" %}
                                 <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="todaylink" id= {{forloop.parentloop.counter0}}  >Today</a>
                            {% endif %}
                        </td>

                {% endfor %}
                </tr>
                <br>

            {% endfor %}

        </table>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Expenditure" />
    </form>
```

and template looks like :

[image]

What i want is to have a header for delete check box as well .. just next to amount . I tried adding one more header but seems its not working as intended . Can someone provide any advices .. Below is how it looks after adding one more header

```
    <form id="expenditure_form" method="post"  action="/moni/add_expenditure/">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table border=10>
            <tr>
                <th>Serial No.</th>
                <th><label >Date:</label></th>
                <th><label for="id_description">Description:</label></th>
                <th><label for="id_amount">Amount</label></th>
                <th><label for="id_delete">Delete</label></th>
            </tr>

            {{ formset.management_form }}
            {% for form in formset %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
                    {% for field in form %}
                        <td>  {{ field.class }} {{ field }}
                            {% if field.name == "exp_date" %}
                                 <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="todaylink" id= {{forloop.parentloop.counter0}}  >Today</a>
                            {% endif %}
                        </td>

                {% endfor %}
                </tr>
                <br>

            {% endfor %}

        </table>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Expenditure" />
    </form>
```

[image]

Any Advice as to how to create this header above delete check box ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is

```
{% for field in form %}
    <td>  {{ field.class }} {{ field }}
        {% if field.name == "exp_date" %}
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="todaylink" id= {{forloop.parentloop.counter0}}    >Today</a>
        {% endif %}
    </td>
{% endfor %}
```

This create 5 TD and you have 4 TD in header.

Please try this

```
<tr>
            <th>Serial No.</th>
            <th><label >Date:</label></th>
            <th><label for="id_description">Description:</label></th>
            <th><label for="id_amount">Amount</label></th>
            <th></th>
            <th><label for="id_delete">Delete</label></th>
</tr>
```

Also you can remove element before delete checkbox.